# parsing JSON data between view controllers

Tags: ios, json, swift, uipickerview

This code gets the JSON data and displays on the view controller that this code is housed within. I am trying to figure out how to use the results from this page on another view controller will most the code from the second view controller below that I am trying to get the results of the code to display on.

```
      func paraseData()
{

    fetchedFiName = []

    let url = ""
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error")
        }
        else{

            do{
                let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! NSArray
                //print(fecthdata)

                for eachFetchedfiName in fetchedData {
                    let eachfiName = eachFetchedfiName as! [String :Any]
                    let fiName = eachfiName["financial_institution"] as! String
                    let oneYear = eachfiName["one_year"] as! String
                    let twoYear = eachfiName["two_year"] as! String
                    let threeYear = eachfiName["three_year"] as! String
                    let fourYear = eachfiName["four_year"] as! String
                    let fiveYear = eachfiName["five_year"] as! String


                    self.fetchedFiName.append(rates(fiName: fiName, oneYear: oneYear, twoYear: twoYear, threeYear: threeYear, fourYear: fourYear, fiveYear: fiveYear))

                }

                //print(self.fetchedFiName)
                self.mtgRates.reloadData()


            }

            catch{
                print("Error 2")
            }
        }

    }
    task.resume()
}


}
class rates {

var fiName: String
var oneYear: String
var twoYear: String
var threeYear: String
var fourYear: String
var fiveYear: String

init(fiName: String, oneYear: String, twoYear: String, threeYear: String, fourYear: String, fiveYear: String) {
    self.fiName = fiName
    self.oneYear = oneYear
    self.twoYear = twoYear
    self.threeYear = threeYear
    self.fourYear = fourYear
    self.fiveYear = fiveYear

}

}
```

This is the code that I am trying to pass the results to on the second view controller. I am trying to populate the pickerview with the names of lenders in in the JSON data... I have been struggling with this problem for days... thoughts please.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    return fetchedFiName[row].fiName
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return fetchedFiName.count
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    lenderName.text = fetchedFiName[row].fiName
    self.view.endEditing(false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Investigate](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html) seques. When leaving your current view controller you can set a value(s) on your destination view controller. The code will look something like:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destinationViewController = segue.destination as! YourViewController
    destinationViewController.json = yourJSONObj
}
```